# Parsing JSON Web Token Claims in Go

Tags: go, jwt

I am trying to do some authentication with JSON Web Tokens and I've managed to generate the token with the correct claims, but I'm having trouble parsing the claims my subsequent requests.

My token looks something like this

```
{
    "Raw": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...",
    "Method": {
        "Name": "RS256",
        "Hash": 5
    },
    "Header": {
        "alg": "RS256",
        "typ": "JWT"
    },
    "Claims": {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    "Signature": "",
    "Valid": false
}
```

and my goal is to parse the `foo` value from the claims. I'm using [this](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go) package for working with web tokens.

I'm able to successfully extract the token from the `Authorization` header, but when I try this

```
token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    return apiKeyPair.PublicKey, nil
})

if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && token.Valid {
    return claims, nil
} else {
    return nil, err
}
```

I'm not getting an error here, but when I try to access `foo` from the claims like this

```
claims, err := GetWebTokenClaims(r)
if err != nil {
    return
}

foo := claims["foo"]
```

I get `nil`. I've tried a number of little tweaks to this structure–like using [custom claims](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/blob/master/example_test.go#L56) with the `ParseWithClaims()` method–but for the life of me I can't get this simple thing working.

Not sure where to go from here or what other info might be relevant, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You haven't posted the full code here, but I'm guessing you can try to check the claims earlier  


`if claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims); ok && token.Valid {
    fmt.Println(claims["foo"])
} else {
    fmt.Println(err)
}`

Answer (score 1):

Define a type that describes the claims and that includes the `jwt.StandardClaims`:

```
type myClaims struct {
    Foo    string   `json:"foo"`
    jwt.StandardClaims
}
```

If you have a JWT with this `data`

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

you can access the claims like this:

```
parsedToken, err := jwt.Parse(signed, keyfunc)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("token is invalid: ", err)
} else {
    claims := parsedToken.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    fmt.Println(claims["foo"])
}
```